# Getting AVPlayer CC/SAP List

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer

I am trying to get a list of all the available closed captions and SAP assets for a given stream but I havent been able to find a way to do this.

I have tried outputting **availableChapterLocales**, **availableMetadataFormats**, and **trackGroups** which didnt result in anything.

When I set **closedCaptionDisplayEnabled** I see closed captions on the player, so I know that they are there somewhere.

Does anyone know how I can get this information?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.